# MS AD2008 - Unable to force password change at next login using Perl Net::LDAPS and userAccountControl attribute

Tags: perl, active-directory, netldap

I am connecting to an Active Directory 2008 Domain Controller using perl Net::LDAPS and trying to set the "User must change password at next logon" account option and it's not working.

I am able to create, modify, delete, and move different objects but I am not able to get that change password setting to take!

This is what I am trying to do and it's not working:

Note: I am using a self written class wrapper for Net::LDAPS and the code below is boiled down to the bare bones of what I am trying to do.

```
# Binding to LDAP Directory:
$self->{LDAP_INSTANCE} = Net::LDAPS->new($host);
$self->{LDAP_INSTANCE}->bind(dn=>$dn, password=>$password, version=>3 )

my $rc =$self->{LDAP_INSTANCE}->modify(
    $DN_OF_USER_ACCOUNT, 
    [ replace => [userAccountControl => 0x00800000] ]
);
print $rc->error; # Results in an empty string / No error

# Note: I have also tried: hex(800000) instead of 0x00800000 as well.
```

I am binding with a domain administrator account and I have verified that the $DN_OF_USER_ACCOUNT is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `userAccountControl` attribute is a bitfield with many settings.  Changing the value for the user to be `0x00800000` would be quite harmful since it would remove the default of `0x200 ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT`.

The [documentation for `0x00800000`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832(v=vs.85).aspx) is:

> 0x00800000 
> ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED
>   The user password has expired. This flag is created by the system using data from the Pwd-Last-Set attribute and the domain policy.

If we look at [`pwdLastSet`'s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430(v=vs.85).aspx), we see:

> The date and time that the password for this account was last changed. [...] If this value is set to 0 and the User-Account-Control attribute does not contain the UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD flag, then the user must set the password at the next logon.

So to expire the password, we need to set `pwdLastSet` to zero.  This is substantiated by a [blog entry from Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/06/how-can-i-cause-a-user-s-password-to-expire.aspx) who does it in VBScript.

In Perl:

```
# Binding to LDAP Directory:
$self->{LDAP_INSTANCE} = Net::LDAPS->new($host);
$self->{LDAP_INSTANCE}->bind(dn=>$dn, password=>$password, version=>3 )

my $rc =$self->{LDAP_INSTANCE}->modify(
    $DN_OF_USER_ACCOUNT, 
    [ replace => [pwdLastSet => 0] ]
);
print $rc->error;
```

Comment: Worked great,  thanks for the explanation along with the correct solution.